# 15.10 Problems :VLC strange screen blinking when going in fullscreen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vlc, 15.10

Yesterday I moved from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 15.10. And now I have problems in VLC. With Nouveau drivers I have image tearing and with Nvidia drivers I have green screen blinking when going in fullscreen, changing aspect ratio, when i go on the bottom of screen. Is this normal or whatl. Later I will post a video of that blinking. on 14.04 there was no image thearing with nouveau and no green blinking with nvidia drivers.

- CPU: FX 8320
- CPU Cooler: ZALMAN CNPS10X OPTIMA
- MBO: ASUS M5A97 R2.0
- RAM: TRANSCEND 2X4 GB 1600 MHZ (8GB)
- HDD: WD BLUE 1TB SATA 3
- GPU: MSI GTX 760 2GB TF IV GAMING OC
- PSU: FORTRON FSP RAIDER 550W 80+ SILVER
- CASE: ZALMAN Z3 PLUS ATX USB 3.0

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: ditto; using nvidia 355.11 driver

Comment: using 362 and still the same